# Azure push notification to Windows desktop

Tags: azure, push-notification

I have a requirement to send push notification to Windows PC.
From this page,
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/

it seems like it is only possible to send notification to Windows store app.
My question is, is it possible to send push notification to Windows 7 like what PushBullet has done?

thanks!

Comment: What about using signalr instead?

Comment: What did you end up implementing? I have a similar requirement. Tks

Comment: We end up developing for chrome extension instead. Windows 7 is such an old OS, it doesn't support push notifications. If you must support win 7 maybe consider using websocket.

Comment: @LeoChen I need similar requirement on Windows 10. Is there any way ?